# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when enter domain name but OK when enter public IP address

Tags: networking, dns, vps

I am building my personal website with Digital Ocean and GoDaddy.

I can visit my website by public IP address but can not visit by domain name.

Following is the setting in Digital Ocean:
[Setting in DO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XAnv.png)

Following is the setting in Godaddy:
[Setting in GoDaddy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LAHe.png)

And when I

```
$ dig gesangvollcy.com
```

The result is:
[$ dig gesangvollcy.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfpu3.png)

Is there something wrong according to above?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your site opens fine using domain name and your DNS settings are OK. You probably have some DNS (caching? hardcoded entry in hosts fie?) issue in your local environment.

Comment: Thanks！It make sense and I can visit now